# Get all list items from various ul elements - merge all of them into a new ul

Tags: jquery

I need to get all list items from 4 different ul elements, and add all of the list items into a new ul.

Say I have this html:

```
<nav id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li>One</li>
        <li>One</li>
        <li>One</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li>Two</li>
        <li>Two</li>
        <li>Two</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<ul id="three">
    <li>three</li>
    <li>three</li>
    <li>three</li>
</ul>
<ul id="four">
    <li>four</li>
    <li>four</li>
    <li>four</li>
</ul>
```

I tried with this:

```
var $three = $('#three').children().clone();
var $four = $('#four').children().clone();
$("#nav li").each(function(index, element) {
    var lists = $(this);
});

$("#result").append(lists).add($three).add($four);
```

-- but obviously it doesn't work. How can this be done?
[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7fxs91bb/) here.

Comment: have you checked the console ,  (index):51 Uncaught ReferenceError: lists is not defined

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/bkt178bp/

Comment: why not just give a class to all the uls that you want to clone, then you can just do something like `$("#result").append($('ul.to-clone > li').clone())`;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just do

```
$("#result").append($("#nav li, #three li, #four li").clone());
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/7fxs91bb/2/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var $result = $('#result');
$('ul').each(function(i, el) {
    $(el).find('li').each(function(i, el) {
        $result.append(el);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this : use append to add li to new ul with `clone()`

```js
$(function(){
 var $result = $('#result');
 $result.append($('#nav ul li').clone());
 $result.append($('#three li').clone());
 $result.append($('#four li').clone());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li>One</li>
        <li>One</li>
        <li>One</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li>Two</li>
        <li>Two</li>
        <li>Two</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<ul id="three">
    <li>three</li>
    <li>three</li>
    <li>three</li>
</ul>
<ul id="four">
    <li>four</li>
    <li>four</li>
    <li>four</li>
</ul>
<ul id="result"></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
$('ul li').each(function(i,o){
    $("#result").append($(o).clone());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check below snippet.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var all_lis = '';
  $('ul').each(function(){
    all_lis += $(this)[0].outerHTML;
  });
  //console.log(all_lis);
  $("#result").html(all_lis);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li>One</li>
        <li>One</li>
        <li>One</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li>Two</li>
        <li>Two</li>
        <li>Two</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<ul id="three">
    <li>three</li>
    <li>three</li>
    <li>three</li>
</ul>
<ul id="four">
    <li>four</li>
    <li>four</li>
    <li>four</li>
</ul>
<ul id='result'></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#result").append($("li").clone());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav id="nav">
  <ul>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>One</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Two</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<ul id="three">
  <li>three</li>
  <li>three</li>
  <li>three</li>
</ul>
<ul id="four">
  <li>four</li>
  <li>four</li>
  <li>four</li>
</ul>
<ul id="result">
</ul>
```